# Are the two meanings of "complete" related?

Tags: logic, computability

In the MathOverflow question "[Are the two meanings of 'undecidable' related](https://mathoverflow.net/q/130789)" and its answers, connections are drawn between undecidability of a statement over a theory and undecidability of a decision problem by Turing machines. For example Joel David Hamkins's answer shows that for a $\Sigma_1$ sound, computably axiomatizable theory $T$, for any Turing-undecidable decision problem $A\subset\mathbb N$, there are infinitely many $n$ such that "$n\in A$?" is undecidable in $T$.

However, are the two meanings of "complete" related? Specifically are there any results connecting computability-theory completeness to a set relevant to the notion of proof-theory completeness?

Comment: If $T$ is $\Sigma_1$-sound and complete, its set of theorems is *never* a complete r.e. set; you're tacitly assuming that $T$ is also computably axiomatizable, which it won't be. The best you can say is that the set of $\Sigma_1$ theorems of $T$ will be a complete r.e. set, but in fact under the above hypotheses it will be a *specific* complete r.e. set regardless of $T$, namely the set of true $\Sigma_1$ sentences.

Comment: Also, if $T$ is complete then for each $n$ its set of theorems is $\Sigma_n$ iff its set of theorems is $\Pi_n$ (and so $\Delta_n$), since we can tell whether $\varphi$ is a theorem by checking whether $\neg\varphi$ is a theorem. So deductive completeness actually pushes *against* complexity-class completeness (there is no $\Delta_n$-complete set for $n>1$).

Comment: Re: my previous comment, note that in computability theory "complete" by default means completeness with respect to many-one reducibility. The halting problem is $\le_T$-complete amongst $\Delta_2$ sets, but it isn't $\le_m$-complete $\Delta_2$.

Comment: You are right, I had overlooked that! I may leave the question up in case it attracts interesting answers, but I will also remove some of the text currently there.